# Is filtering requests on the server CPU-intensive?

Tags: security, web-scraping, server, cloud, ddos

I've been reading through Jonas Czech's popular [How To Prevent Scraping](https://github.com/JonasCz/How-To-Prevent-Scraping) guide to help prevent harvesting of content on a Laravel site I'm responsible for. Several of the guide's suggestions involve filtering requests by identifiers like IP address and user agent, and then either blocking them or showing challenges like reCAPTCHAs. Presumably this sort of filtering would be most efficiently done at the server configuration level using Nginx config files or Apache's htaccess, but can also be done in application code.

The problem is that I've seen it stated in a few places elsewhere that filtering requests on my own server - as opposed to on the cloud by putting Cloudflare in front of the site and using their many equivalent offerings - can result in the server quickly becoming overloaded with requests (and therefore DOSed or DDOSed).

If my site is running on a cheap VPS like a Digital Ocean droplet, is implementing such a feature likely to make the server fall over? Or in other words, does filtering incoming requests typically add a high overhead to the server's compute?

Comment: While your question is inviting a lot of opinion based responses, and as such doesn't meet this site's standards, I did peruse that guide. My conclusion? It's so, so last summer.  Why are you worried about scraping? If your content should be protected, then put it behind a login wall. The more effective anti-scraping solution you will get, the more expensive they will be, and ultimately (if not from the start) they'll become obsolete. You can have ToS for your site, and that will prevent (decent) scrapers. All'n'all, you're trying to fight a losing battle.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what responses you're referring to as so far there have been none. If you're saying it *will* attract opinions, I disagree - the question is a technical one that's objectively answerable to someone who understands the technologies. 2. The client is worried about scraping because they understandably don't want their copy and articles being stolen by their competitors, which is common in their industry. Articles cannot be behind login walls for obvious reasons. A ToS is about as effective as robots.txt - it's completely ignored by those you actually need to pay attention to it.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I'm not sure what point you're trying to make about effectiveness and losing battles, but it sounds to me like you've fallen prey to the nirvana fallacy, which a lot of people in tech fall to when it comes to scraping. Just because a 100% effective solution doesn't exist doesn't mean we should settle for 0% - the more % you can stop the less work on your (client's) legal team. To extend this to an analogy that those in tech are less likely to fall prey to, just because wearing a mask is not 100% effective at preventing COVID doesn't mean you don't wear one at all.

Comment: I actually agree with the Covid/mask analogy, however your comment is a bit conflicting with your original question: once you have a legal team, why would you choose a cheap VPS? It doesn't compute.  And no, your question is not technical, it's inviting opinions, and it's not within SOF standards.